# SQL select statements

Tags: sql

How do I use SELECT statement just to select people having email address,
The constrains are that if the email address is ‘abc@gmail.com’, then display only abc i.e. starting with first character and ending till @ symbol.

Comment: Maybe something like `SELECT SPLIT_PART(address, '@', 1)` for `postgresql`

Comment: which dbms you are using?

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
  REPLACE(SUBSTRING(EmailAddressColumn,1,CHARINDEX('@',EmailAddressColumn)),'@','') 
  FROM TableName
```

Would do it in SQL Server.

It would help to know what database server you're running, and what version (e.g. SQL Server 2016, MariaDb 10.5, etc)

Answer (score 0):

If you are using sql server

> ```
> select substring('abc@bbb',1,charindex('@','abc@bbb')-1)
> GO
> ```

> | (No column name) |
> | --- |
> | abc |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=47713dd73f5370b62bfb76c7ddf040d0)*

Comment: @Sangamesh_Varma Please let me know if you are strill facing any difficulties with this query.